Convert C++ typesafe enum to C# enum using swig
I have a library with typesafe enums in the following form:
struct MyEnum {
  enum Value { One, Two, Three };

  MyEnum() : value(-1) {}
  MyEnum(Value v) : value(v) {}

  Value value;
};

And I want swig to ignore the struct and just convert it to a regular C# enum like so:
public enum MyEnum { One, Two, Three }

So far, I've tried using %rename with the flatnested feature but it doesn't generate the enum.
%include <enums.swg>
%feature("flatnested");
%rename(MyEnum) MyEnum::Value;
%ignore MyEnum;

struct MyEnum {
  enum Value { One, Two, Three };
};

Yet if I use an anonymous enum nested within a struct it works fine.
%include <enums.swg>
%feature("flatnested");
%rename(MyEnum) MyEnum::Value;
%ignore MyEnum;

struct MyEnum {
  struct Value {
    enum { One, Two, Three };
  };
};


What do you mean by "nothing works"? What doesn't work, what errors you get?

Typesafe enums were added in C++ 11 with the enum class or enum struct syntax, eg enum class Color { red, green = 20, blue }. What you posted is one of the techniques used to emulate this before C++ 11. Value isn't a nested class, it's still an Enum.

@kiner_shah No errors. It simply doesn't generate the enum.

@PanagiotisKanavos This is a library that was created before enum classes existed. I need to adapt them as is without changing the original source.

The edit just proves that flatnested requires actual classes and structs, and won't work with enums. It's not just a string replacement feature
